# UIalert view not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am new to objective C and I am in a position where I need to create an iPhone App Really quickly , I am using XCode 4.2

I want to have a pop up and I am using this code :

in the .h I have

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

and in the .m file

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" 
                                                     message:@"confirmed" 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
                          [alert show];
```

the code shows me a building error "Expected identifier" , did I forget something ?

Thanks

Comment: To check matching brackets, parens, braces just double click one and if there is a match the selection will highlite. Nice quick test.

Comment: extra bracket. delete one of them before you alloc it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra open bracket '['

you need something like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" 
                                                     message:@"confirmed" 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
                          [alert show];
```

Note the **autorelease]** code I added, this way you set to autorelease the UIAlertView and fix the extra open bracket.

Comment: Xcode 4.2 - so I'm guessing that the OP's using ARC, and hence the autorelease call is not needed.

Comment: Good point, then no autorelease is needed, just remove the extra open bracket =)

Comment: Also note that he was using `nil` twice on the `otherButtonTitles:` argument... I doubt that could cause harm but it's not good practice certainly

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors :

`->[<-`[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" 
                                                     message:@"confirmed" 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil`->,nil<-]`;

delete them and just write :

```
[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" 
                           message:@"confirmed" 
                          delegate:self 
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

If you are not using ARC, don't forget to release `[alert release]` after `[alert show]`  (or `autorelease` at the end of the init)